# unable to deploy the python pyramid web apps to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyramid

[image]

This is the Error logs I find in the heroku when deploying the python pyramid application. I have followed the each and every steps the python pyramid documentation has. Where have I exactly missed not able to figure out.

I doubt if my way of creating run file is incorrect. I have created a run.py

```
file and added the following code into it.
#!/bin/bash
set -e
python setup.py develop
python runapp.py
```

Comment: Please show your Procfile.

Comment: her is my Profile content web: ./run

Answer (score 0):

You cannot host a web app like that. You need a proper server, for example gunicorn - see the Pyramid docs on [how to run with gunicorn](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gunicorn.html), that is what needs to go in your Procfile. You don't need a run.py.

Comment: added the gunicorn on the setup.py inside require as dependencies and run a setup and pushed to heroku again still same problem

Comment: WHAT DOES this means copying from log -->app[web.1]: bash: ./run: Is a directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Profile

```
 web: ./run
```

run

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
python setup.py develop
python runapp.py
```

runapp.py

```
#Heroku Startup
import os

from paste.deploy import loadapp
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to='.')

    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

requirements.txt

```
pyramid
pyramid_chameleon
pyramid_debugtoolbar
waitress

<add other dependencies here>
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.3.0     #or whatever version you are running.  Take this out
```

Comment: Thats what my runapp.py look like BTW is that run only or run.py

Comment: WHAT DOES this means copying from log "" app[web.1]: bash: ./run: Is a directory ""

Comment: The file (not a direcrory) should be "run". Not "run.py". Make sure it is executable.

Comment: I added two other files in my answer.  I was not sure if you had them already.